# 2 processes access the same text file on sd card at the same time

Tags: android, multithreading, multiprocessing

Say both Process A and B update the file.

The Process can be background Service, active Activity and can be from different application.

I want to know that how Android handles this kind of scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Operating system level [file locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking). Android is built on top of Linux.